# jQuery Simulate onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to simulate an `onclick` event on a drop down.

I have an IE object that is going to a page and I need to change a dropdown which has an `onchange` event:

```
$('select[name="blah"]').val(3).trigger('change');


$('select[name="blah"]').change(function(){
   alert('changed'); 
});
```

When I try this, I would expect the alert to fire as it's technically an `onchange`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3y5hmyf0/

Is there a way to acomplish this?

**More Details**

My tool is controlling another IE page through an object. It navigates to the page and finds the select drop down on the page. From there, if you did it manually it has an onchange event when making a selection.

I am trying to get jQuery to simulate as if it was being clicked by a person to it triggers that on change event.

I have tried `.trigger` and `.change` and couldnt get either of them to work.

Comment: strange, tried it in FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason your code does not work is the order you are executing it. You need to connect the handler before triggering it:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3y5hmyf0/1/

```
// Wire up event handler
$('select[name="blah"]').change(function(){
   alert('changed'); 
});

// Now generate the event
$('select[name="blah"]').val(3).trigger('change');
```

Note: Your manual `change` trigger is still required as a change event must normally be triggered by user interaction. Setting the value is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name="blah"]').change(function(){
   NotifyChanged();
});

function NotifyChanged() {
    alert('changed'); 
}
```

If you want to test the logic in the changed function, just call it.

Comment: May I ask why it would work calling a function but not if the alert was in the on change event directly?

Comment: Your code can call the function instead of trying to simulate a click.